# Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. while -[parsedxmlstring isEqualToString:textviewstring]?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, xml-parsing, exc-bad-access

Shortly, I am parsing a xml file and getting user MD5 password. Now when i am comparing parsed password and user given password in a text field then i am finding `Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”`

when i do not compare between these password then code execute.Here is my code.

```
if([checkingParsedPassword isEqualToString:passwordMD5String]){
tabbarController = [[TabbarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabbarController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *myTabbarController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabbarController] autorelease];
myTabbarController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:myTabbarController animated:YES];
[tabbarController release];    
}
```

If i have to give u any more information then please don't hesitate because i am in serious problem.

**EDIT**

when i am using `NSLog`...i can see both string.

```
 NSLog(@"The parsed pass: %@ and the user pass: %@ ",checkingParsedPassword, passwordMD5String);
```

but when i try to compare then i got these exc_bad_access on `if` condition

```
if([checkingParsedPassword isEqualToString:passwordMD5String]){
    NSLog(@"checked");
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `tabbarController` & `myTabbarController`?

Comment: actually i have missed my code.i have updated my code.

Comment: Well, where did you declare your `tabbarController`? I think you declared it in your `.h` file, if so, you need to release it in `dealloc` method instead of here.

Comment: i have no problem in modal view change.i am sure about that because i have checked it without `if` condition and then it works fine.

Comment: @YamenEmon Your checkingParsedPassword is probably getting deallocated. Log both strings before comparison and show the code where you assign them.

Comment: Please every body see my edited code.i am being strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converted password from md5 might not be a UTF8string,so try converting md5 password in a string like

```
passwordMD5String=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",passwordMD5String];
```

before comparing.

Comment: yes i have converted it and i can get these both value `passwordMD5String` and `checkingParsedPassword` using `nslog`.

Comment: Can you try putting breakpoint and tell me the line on which it is crashing,because your code seems to be correct.

Comment: without `if` condition it works really fine but when i use `if` then it shows me this problem

Comment: if you can share both the strings to me i could check out.?

Comment: Thats what I am telling you isEqualToString method expects a string but md5 password could be some other format string,so you will be able to print it.

Comment: `NSString *convertingPasswordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",passwordMD5String];` can you tell me why i get Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” error here?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this as I think.
Just for a check try printf("%s",[passwordMD5String UTF8String]).Let me know whether it crashes and if doesnot work out please send me the md5 string.

Comment: whatever just skip it.can you tell me how can i convert md5 to nsstring?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling both `-release` and `-autorelease` on the tabbarController variable (which changes name in the middle of the code for some reason--were you trying to clean it up when posting?).